# Unmarshal XML with unescaped & character inside

Tags: go

I have a url with a ampersand symbol inside of a xml file that I am trying to unmarshal. I cannot change the response data I get so how can I escape it so that I can unmarshal it.

error:  XML syntax error on line 2: invalid character entity &user (no semicolon)

http://play.golang.org/p/XB8aPJY4Nw

Comment: This response _is_ invalid XML. As a workaround, you can use a regex finding all ampersands not followed by an XML entity string _and_ a semicolon _within_ a tag and replace those with either the URL-encoded or XML-encoded ampersand. Erm, good luck with the regex...;)

Comment: RFC: Canonical XML Version 1.0 - https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3076.txt. "The string value of the node is modified by replacing all ampersands (&) with &amp;, all open angle brackets (<) with &lt;, all quotation mark (double quote) characters with &quot;, and the whitespace characters #x9, #xA, and #xD, with character references.  The character references are written in uppercase hexadecimal with no leading zeroes (for example, #xD is represented by the character reference &#xD;)"

Answer (score 8):

After reading through the `encoding/xml` docs I found that one can turn off strict mode which enforces the char values. In my case I know my constants that will be returned and am safe doing so. Thanks for all the responses.

This is a snippet from [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder):

> In attribute values and character data, unknown or malformed
>   character entities (sequences beginning with &) are left alone.
>
> ```
> d.Strict = false;
> ```

[Playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/DRv8Mfhn3_).